# Excel vba copy range style to new location

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a problem that I'm partway through solving but falling short. The remaining problem.

Range A1:D10 are set to a colour (manually) I need a button I can click to copy the cell style only to K1:O10 without copying the value of removing the existing contents only overwriting the style.

Not sure if this will be a factor but A5:D5 is merged (but so is K5:O5.

Comment: Can you show us your code you have so far?

Comment: Columns A:D is 4 columns, but columns K:O are 5 columns.  Which cells formats do you want to copy where?  (E.g. A1 to K1, B1 to L1, C1 to M1, D1 to N1, and D1 also to O1?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. I only know how to paste it in a cell one at a time

```
Range("A1:D10").Copy
Range("K5").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
Range("L5").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
Range("M5").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
Range("N5").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
Range("O5").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
```

Comment: That worked perfect, pasting to 1 cell does the job because it copies the whole range! Perfect thankyou

Comment: I'm sure there's a way where you don't have to call one cell at a time, but nothing seemed to work for me